# Increment NSSlider by 0.1? macOS, Swift

Tags: swift, macos, nsslider

I have a NSSlider where the minimum is 0.6 and maximum is 1.

I want to be able to increment by 0.1 and not have values such as 0.6493 or 0.8435

How would I accomplish this?

I have the function

```
@IBAction func slider(sender : NSSlider) {
    var x: Double = sender.doubleValue
    // do something
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check if `NSSlider` has methods or properties to support an increment of 0.1?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this format  :

```
@IBAction func slider(sender : NSSlider) {

  let value = sender.value

  // "%.1f" show how many decimals you want to show
  let formatted = String(format: "%.1f", value)

  //formatted will be printed 0.X

}
```

Comment: @Andrew How does this answer the question?

Comment: @Willeke what do you mean? It update correctly!? Why is it wrong?

Comment: If the question was "How do I create a string from a Double", this could be a correct answer but the question was about `NSSlider` and increments. Moreover, the code doesn't compile.